# How do you make crossing wires not connect in EAGLE?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, wire, keypad

I am brand new to PCB designing (started yesterday) and am doing it as a fun little side project. My goal is to produce a working PCB that has a very basic function. My problem is this:

I have no idea how to make wires (I think called a net in EAGLE) "cross" without connecting to each other. I was thinking of having little soldering hole type things either side of the wire (the one that is part of the PCB), and soldering another wire to them to jump over the other wire inside the PCB (hopefully, that made sense), but I would have to have 100 holes and 50 wires for this project.

I was wondering if there is a much more efficient way of doing this? I have heard the term "Air Wires" thrown around a lot but I do not know if this is what I need, as well as double-sided PCBs. At the moment I am using a single-sided PCB but that can change

Edit: Sorry I am bad with terminology for things like this. I have tried to make it more clear but please point out any mistakes I have made or if you need any clarification.

Comment: Are you making a single-sided board or a double-sided board?

Comment: it is unclear what wires you are asking about ..... is it the "wire" in a schematic or is it a trace on a PCB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common practice is to use a two-layer board with tracks (wires) on both sides.  Vias (small plated holes) are used to connect the tracks on the top side to those on the bottom side.

If you get the boards made by a commercial board shop the holes will normally be plated to provide connections between the sides.  If you make the boards yourself, you'll have to solder wires in the via holes to make the connection.

If you only have a single-sided board (tracks on only one side), the wire jumpers you suggest could be used - many commercial products have single-sided boards with wire jumpers.  You may have to route the board manually to minimize the number of jumpers.

EDIT - Additional suggestion:

Even if you are making a single-sided board, lay it out in Eagle as if it was to be a double-sided board, then when building the board, replace the tracks shown on the non-copper side with your wire jumpers.  This will allow Eagle's Design Rule Check (DRC) function to check your board layout against the schematic, and tell you of any missed or incorrect connections.

The "air wires" you mention are the lines that Eagle PCB uses to show the required connections.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try making it a 2 sided PCB and use some Vias to get the connection to the other side as that will allow me to use less resources